# Can Virtual Hosts in Apache loads any directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

windows 7 Hosts file...

```
127.0.0.1       www.test.com
```

---

httpd-vhosts file...  MY-IP-IS-HERE is my actual IP...

```
NameVirtualHost MY-IP-IS-HERE

<VirtualHost MY-IP-IS-HERE>
 ServerName test.com
 DocumentRoot "E:/Web Server/xampp/htdocs/test/ajaxblog"
 DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html index.htm index.shtml
</VirtualHost>
```

For some reason, when I go to **test.com or www.test.com** it loads **E:/Web Server/xampp/htdocs/** instead of loading **E:/Web Server/xampp/htdocs/test/ajaxblog** and I cannot figure out how to get virtual host to load anything deeper then my root directory.  Am I doing something wrong?  I am using Apache or Xampp on Windows 7

Comment: What does your error/access log say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.test.com doesn't work because you don't have a ServerAlias setup for www.test.com

Comment: hello I have added  ServerAlias www.test.com but it still loads my root directory instead of root/test/ajaxblog any ideas?

Comment: You have quotes around your document root; Try removing them...

Comment: You need the quotes as you have spaces in your path.  I don't think it is that.

Comment: Wasn't paying attention, your correct.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jacobs answer on adding a `ServerAlias www.test.com`, you should restart Apache to make the change take effect. Make sure that you have not double `ServerName test.com` entries in your virtualhost configuration.